# conversion from `const char*' to `byte'

Tags: c++, char, byte, converters

I have trouble converting const char to byte. I'm reading  file using ifstream and it gives me content as string then I'm converting string to const char using c_str(); and then trying insert it to byte array for packet sending purpose. I'm new to c++ and can't understand how I must convert char to byte and need your help guys. here is my piece of code please give me some advice

```
byte buf[42];

const char* fname = path.c_str();

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(fname);//open the input file

stringstream strStream;
strStream << inFile.rdbuf();//read the file
string str = strStream.str();//str holds the content of the file

vector<string> result = explode(str,',');

for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
    buf[i] = result[i].c_str(); // Here is Error
    cout << "\"" << result[i] << "\"" << endl;
}

system("pause");
```

This is data which i take from file : (0x68,0x32,0x01,0x7B,0x01,0x1F,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 )

Comment: How is this `byte` type defined ? It's not part of standard c++...

Comment: You are trying to store a pointer to a string in an array of bytes. 1 byte cannot hold a whole string. I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: `byte` is not a standard type of C++11. Do you mean [int8_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) ?

Comment: i'm creating hex values from php code, then i'm saving this into file, then i'm opening this file using C++ code and want assign this hex values to byte array, yea i know i'm making something wrong but i can't figure out how i must do correctly =/

Comment: Does the file you read contain the text "0x68 ...", i.e. the letter '0' followed by the letter 'x' etc, as you would see it in an editor? (That would make the file size >60.) Or does it contain about 15 bytes, the first one having the value 0x68?

Comment: `buf[i] = result[i].c_str();` should be `buf[i] = result.c_str()[i];`

Comment: yes but will it inserts into buff[i] like this { 0x68,0x32,0x01 }etc... ?

Comment: C++ defines "byte" as the amount of storage taken by `char`.  It doesn't always agree with the definition of "byte" used by the underlying platform.

Comment: yes but all i want is take this string value 0x68,0x32 etc.. and put it into byte buf[46]  <- this array and get like this buf[46] = {0x68,0x32, etc...} how i must do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it by myself, now i will explain solution. so i wanted String(0x68,0x32,0x03,0x22 etc..) variable split per "," and then convert it into hex value after all input it into byte array as 16 bit hex values.

```
char buf[42]; // Define Packet

const char* fname = path.c_str(); // File Location


ifstream inFile; //
inFile.open(fname);//open the input file

stringstream strStream;
strStream << inFile.rdbuf();//read the file
string str = strStream.str();//str holds the content of the file



vector<string> result = explode(str,','); // Explode Per comma


for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) { // loop for every exploded value

unsigned int x;   
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex <<  result[i];    // Convert String Into Integer value 
ss >> x;
buf[i] = x;

 printf(&buf[i],"%04x",x); //Convert integer value back to 16 bit hex value and store into array


    }



  system("pause");
```

thanks all for replay.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign a character string (many characters) to a single byte.  It won't fit.
Try something like

Add this before the start of the loop:

```
size_t bufpos = 0;
```

then inside the loop

```
const string & str = resulti[i];
for (size_t strpos = 0; strpos < str.size() && bufpos < sizeof(buf); ++strpos)
{
   buf[bufpos++] = str[strpos];
}
```

Comment: yes but exploding string (0x68,0x32,0x01,0x7B,0x01,0x1F,0x00 ...) as 1 hex value and need put array[0]=0x68 like this, and i want have byte array similar of this  byte buf[42] = {

                            0x68,0x32,0x01,0x7B,0x01,0x1F,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                            0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,
                            0x12,0x00,0x57,0x12,0x00,0x65,0x12,0x00,0x6C,0x12,0x00,0x63,0x12,0x00,0x6F,0x12,0x00,0x6D,0x12,0x00,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                            0x86,0x03

                       }

Comment: Its kind of hard to answer your question when you keep changing your goal and adding new elements.  Where did `array[0]` come from?  I suggest you take a step back and define what you are trying to achieve, rather than focusing low level problems with the approach you have taken.

Comment: i mean byte buf[0] as array[0]  but anyway, please answer me if you know, if i have string try = "0x23" is it possible convert this string as byte value and insert it into byte buf[1] = { 0x23 }, (sorry for my english)

Comment: @DTDest So what you really want is to take a string containing the hexadecimal representation of a number and extract that number into a `byte` (whatever that is)?

Comment: yes i want this, take 0x23 this string value convert it as hex 0x23 and put it into byte array. please tell me what i must do if you know =/